How can I avoid N+1 query issues when checking friend statuses in a list with Drizzle ORM?
Im using Drizzle ORM
I have this code in business layer to get list of users and represent them as Friend List
export const getFriendList = async (sessionUserId: number, userId: number) => {
    const friendList = await db
        .select({
            id: usersTable.id,
            name: usersTable.name,
            username: usersTable.username,
            avatar: usersTable.avatar,
            created_at: usersTable.created_at,
        })
        .from(friendshipsTable)
        .innerJoin(
            usersTable,
            or(
                and(
                    eq(friendshipsTable.user_id, userId),
                    eq(friendshipsTable.friend_id, usersTable.id),
                    ne(friendshipsTable.friend_id, sessionUserId),
                ),
                and(
                    eq(friendshipsTable.user_id, usersTable.id),
                    eq(friendshipsTable.friend_id, userId),
                    ne(friendshipsTable.user_id, sessionUserId),
                ),
            ),
        );

    return friendList;
}

One way to achieve it is to map through it and make query check to each, but not a good practice
const friendListWithStatus = friendList.map(async (friend) => {
    const { isFriend, hasRequest, requestFrom } = await checkFriendStatus(
      sessionUserId,
      friend.id // Use friend.id for each item in friendList
    );

    return {
      ...friend, // Include all friend details
      isFriend,
      hasRequest,
      requestFrom,
    };
  });

const friendListWithStatusResolved = await Promise.all(friendListWithStatus);

return {
    isFriend, 
    hasRequest, 
    requestFrom, 
    friendList: friendListWithStatusResolved,
};

My expected output is
{
 "id": 6,
 "name": "Rodel",
 "username": "cazcade1",
 "avatar": "/m_avatar_1.svg",
 "created_at": "2024-08-18T21:43:00.916Z",
 "isFriend": false,
 "hasRequest": true,
 "requestFrom": "us",
}

I have tried to make sql query inside the select but I don't think it is a valid sql query.
